# qsort() not working for array of number

Tags: c, struct, quicksort, qsort

Actually i have to create huffman tree for that i need to sort the frequency and i am using qsort() function for that.
But when i try to display the frequency it show still the same pattern (Not the sorted one).
Here is my code:-

```
        struct node
        {
            int value;
            char letter;                 /* symbol */
            struct node *left,*right;    /* left and right subtrees */
        };
    typedef struct node Node;
//Given below is the frequency of all 27 alphabets
int englishLetterFrequencies [27] = {81, 15, 28, 43, 128, 23, 20, 61, 71, 2, 1, 40, 24, 69, 76, 20, 1, 61, 64, 91, 28, 10, 24, 1, 20, 1, 130};
```

here is my function where i try to build huffman (its inside the main() ):

```
/*builds the huffman tree and returns its address by reference*/

    void buildHuffmanTree(Node **tree){
        Node *temp;
        Node *array[27];
        int i, subTrees = 27;
        int smallOne;

        for (i=0;i<27;i++)
        {
            array[i] = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            array[i]->value = englishLetterFrequencies[i];
            array[i]->letter = i;
            array[i]->left = NULL;
            array[i]->right = NULL;
        }
         smallOne=sorting(array); //this function is responsible for sorting. I HAVE QSORT() CALL IN THIS FUNCTION

    return;
}
```

see its function definition :

```
int sorting(Node *array[])
{
    int smaller;
    int i = 0; int d,p;
    printf("the array frequency is \n");
    for(d=0;d < 27;d++)
    printf("%d  ",*array[d]);
    // sorting of arrays
    qsort(array,27,sizeof(*array),&cmpfunc); 
    //////////////////////////
    printf("\n the sorted array frequency is \n");
        for(p=0;p < 27;p++)
    printf("%d  ",*array[p]);

    return smaller;
}
```

whereas the cmpfunc() is here like this //PROBABLY MISTAKE IS HERE

```
 int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
    {
          return ( ((Node *)a)->value - ((Node *)b)->value );
    }
```

Any idea why it don't sort the arrays ?

Comment: Should `qsort(*array` be `qsort(array` ? And cmpfunc gets a lot more readable (and less error-prone) if it contains actual `Node*` variables that you initialize from the `void*` args, IMHO.

Comment: IF I PUT "*array" (instead of "array") at the place of first argument (in order to make some changes and then if i see output,Its shows that in the first two position is 0 but list is still unsorted) and when i put just "array" it again shows the same list of frequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparator is wrong, and your assumption of how `qsort` works isn't far behind it.

For sorting a pointer array of `Node*` you need a comparator like this:

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    const Node **lhs = (const Node **)a;
    const Node **rhs = (const Node **)b;
    return (*lhs)->value < (*rhs)->value ? -1
        : ((*rhs)->value < (*lhs)->value);
}
```

Stripping all the extraneous junk out, including the `sorting()` call and invoking `qsort` directly...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int value;
    char letter;                 /* symbol */
    struct node *left,*right;    /* left and right subtrees */
};
typedef struct node Node;

static const int englishLetterFrequencies [27] =
{
    81, 15, 28, 43, 128, 23,
    20, 61, 71, 2, 1, 40, 24,
    69, 76, 20, 1, 61, 64, 91,
    28, 10, 24, 1, 20, 1, 130
};

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    const Node **lhs = (const Node **)a;
    const Node **rhs = (const Node **)b;
    return (*lhs)->value < (*rhs)->value ? -1
        : ((*rhs)->value < (*lhs)->value);
}

void buildHuffmanTree(Node **tree)
{
    Node *array[27];
    int i;
    
    for (i=0;i<27;i++)
    {
        array[i] = malloc(sizeof(*array[i]));
        array[i]->value = englishLetterFrequencies[i];
        array[i]->letter = (char)i;
        array[i]->left = NULL;
        array[i]->right = NULL;
    }
    
    qsort(array, 27, sizeof(*array), cmpfunc);
    
    for (i=0; i<27; ++i)
        printf("array[%d]->value = %d\n", i, array[i]->value);
    
    return;
}

int main()
{
    buildHuffmanTree(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
array[0]->value = 1
array[1]->value = 1
array[2]->value = 1
array[3]->value = 1
array[4]->value = 2
array[5]->value = 10
array[6]->value = 15
array[7]->value = 20
array[8]->value = 20
array[9]->value = 20
array[10]->value = 23
array[11]->value = 24
array[12]->value = 24
array[13]->value = 28
array[14]->value = 28
array[15]->value = 40
array[16]->value = 43
array[17]->value = 61
array[18]->value = 61
array[19]->value = 64
array[20]->value = 69
array[21]->value = 71
array[22]->value = 76
array[23]->value = 81
array[24]->value = 91
array[25]->value = 128
array[26]->value = 130
```

Spend some time learning how the algorithm works, and don't take shortcuts. You're going to need *two* comparator functions for what it looks like you're ultimately going to do (assuming I understand how you're planning on building your huffman tree).

Comment: that was a big help Whoz ..But i am not able to understand the return part,I mean:- "return (*lhs)->value < (*rhs)->value ? -1
        : ((*rhs)->value < (*lhs)->value ? 1 : 0);" and also why we use 2 ** here :- "const Node **lhs = (const Node **)a;" THANKS FOR THE EXPLANATION

Comment: The `Node**` is because of how `qsort` works. it passes you the *address* of each item in your sequence being compared. In this case that is the address of a pointer, i.e. a `Node*`. The `return` statement in the comparator could be made significantly simpler since you stand no chance of an underflow with your static data, but I prefer to do it the same way without that assumption.

Comment: The comparator only need return negative, zero, or positive, so the subtraction itself is fine - nested ternaries are going to earn a _massively confusing_, too ;)

Comment: @Notlikethat The subtraction is fine for the OP only because of the value-domain. It would *not* be fine as a general solution; Such an example would be the first operand being at or near `INT_MIN` and a resulting subtraction of the second operand triggering underflow. That is the sole reason I use that comparator as a cookie-cutter. If ternaries aren't someone's cup of tea, a if-duo with inline returns would work equally as well, or an if-else-if-else quad if single-return is also desired to reduce the massive confusion overload.

Answer (score 2):

```
 return ( (*(int**)a) - (*(int**)b ));
```

This is casting `a` and `b` as "pointer-to-pointer-to-int", so by dereferencing them only once you then calculate the difference between two pointers. What you mean is:

```
 return ( (*(Node **)a)->value - (*(Node **)b)->value );
```

because whilst `**(int**)a` might work in this case it is *massively* confusing to anyone trying to understand the code.

Edit: sorry, I ended up missing a dereference there myself - fixed.

Also:

```
printf("%d  ",*array[d]);
```

should be

```
printf("%d  ",array[d]->value);
```

for the same reason.

Comment: are you sure that my qsort() is correct ?? Last argument with &cmpfun ?? because i have done the changes you asked me to do..Its still showing the same frequecies and I DON'T KNOW WHY IT GIVES 0 AT THE PLACE OF FIRST TWO FREQUENCIES ?? any idea ?

Comment: @user3085082 sorry, my mistake. I literally confused myself with the `struct`-aliasing-`int` business and ending up missing out the indirection from `qsort()` itself.